# One Android app receives push notifications from two different Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created two Firebase projects for the same Android app.

1. One for **development**
2. Other for **production**.

For **development**, I was compiling my application with my `google-service.json` from the dev Firebase project and now I'm compiling with the file from the **production** Firebase project.

> The problem is I'm still receiving push notifications from the dev
>   project on the app I compiled with the **production**
>   `google-service.json` file. I checked Firebase Settings and every id I
>   have found are different in dev and **production**. So how is it
>   possible that I'm still receiving notifications from the dev project?

Note: I'm not using a back-end to send notifications, I'm doing everything from the Firebase console.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: have you changed the `google-service.json` file with your new project's `google-service.json`

Comment: Yes, I did, actually I can compile my application with one of the two files, no matter which one, I will receive notifications from the two Firebase projects.